# double precision in C++, 308 digits or 15 digits?

Tags: c++, double, precision

If double can represent value up to 3.4E308 (308 zeros), then why do we say that double stores only 15 digits? What is point of saying "ten power of 308" ?

Comment: The value `10000000000000000001` and the value `10000000000000000002` are stored in the same way. You won't be able to tell one from the other. So, the last digit is not significant.

Comment: digits of range ≠ digits of precision

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We *don't* say that "*`double` stores only 15 digits*". We say that "*`double` has 15 digits of precision*". It means that the computed value of `double`, when printed as a base-10 sequence of digits, is accurate only up to those 15 digits.

`double` *can* represent `3.4E308`. Yes, to print it you need more than 15 digits of precision. Some particular values have those guarantees thanks to floating-point implementation. *But*, for example, a number `3.4E308 - 1`, which *is* inside of `double`'s range, *cannot* be represented *accurately* by a `double`.

If you want to be sure, just take the first 15 digits of `double`. Some values can be correctly represented with more than 15 digits, but some cannot. Every value in `double`'s range *will* be correctly represented up to the 15th digit of its decimal representation.

Comment: for double to survive `binary -> decimal -> binary` roundtrip unchanged you need to use 17 decimal digits. In any case, I highly recommend reading about [Ryu algorithm](https://github.com/ulfjack/ryu).

Answer (score 3):

To help perceive this in simple terms, consider a number type that can represent following numbers:

```
-100000
-100
-9
-8
-7
-6
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
0
+1
+2
+3
+4
+5
+6
+7
+8
+9
+100
+100000
```

The type can represent numbers up to 100000. Does this type have 6 digits of precision, or 1?